# Django-MongoDB recursive call

Tags: django, mongodb

I'm a beginner in MongoDB and I'm trying to solve one problem I had with a relational database (using Django). I have a `Song` and `Album` models, and I want each song to have a reference to its Album, and each Album to have a list of all its songs. Is it possible to have something like this in MongoDB :

```
{
'song_title': 'In mist she was standing',
'album': {
   'album_title': 'Orchid',
   'songs': [ { song_title: 'Requiem', album:{'album_title':'Orchid', 'songs':[{song_title'....
```

And that's when we have an endless loop. Is there anyway to achieve this? Maybe I'm not fully understanding the point of MongoDB, I'd be happy if someone could point me to the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to keep it simple at start: two collections `Album` and `Song` just like in any other relational database.

I'm assuing you're using mongoengine as ORM.

```
class Album(Document):
    album_title = StringField()
    songs = ListField(ObjectIdFIeld())
    meta = {
       'indexes': ['songs'],
       'allow_inheritance': False,
    }

class Song(Document):
    song_title = StringField()
    album = ObjectIdField()
    meta = {
       'indexes': ['album']
    }
```

every time you fetch an `Album` you can fetch its songs with a second query (mongodb has no concept of joins):

```
album = Album.objects.all().first() # just an example
songs = Song.objects.filter(id__in=album.songs)
```

Another possibility is to completely embed song into album:

```
class Song(EmbeddedDocument):
    song_title = StringField()

class Album(Document):
    album_title = StringField()
    songs = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Song))
```

Could be better if your queries are (almost) all coming from the `Album` model.

Anyways I suggest starting with the two table setup and then later on you can improve preformance by embedding song data into album.

Hope this helps